# How can i create a [String : AnyObject] array in swift2

Tags: migration, swift2

This code snippet worked with swift but does not compile with swift2.

```
let settings = [
    AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatLinearPCM,
    AVSampleRateKey: 44100.0,
    AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
    AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey: 16,
    AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey: true
]

let audioFile = AVAudioFile(forWriting:url, settings:settings, error:&error)
```

I get a "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" error. If i change the assignment to [String : Any] i get a error at AVAudioFile because it expects a [String : AnyObject] array.

```
let settings:[String : Any] = [
   AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatLinearPCM,
    AVSampleRateKey: 44100.0,
    AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
    AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey: 16,
    AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey: true
]

let audioFile = try! AVAudioFile(forWriting:url, settings:settings)
```

Does anyone know how to create [String : AnyObject] array in swift2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`kAudioFormatLinearPCM` was an UInt32 but Swift 2 wants an Int instead:

```
let settings: [String:AnyObject] = [
    AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatLinearPCM),
    AVSampleRateKey: 44100.0,
    AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
    AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey: 16,
    AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey: true
]
```

Comment: Works perfect. I didn't catch the UInt32 to Int conversion